# How to code for arrow using while loops only

Tags: python, while-loop, accumulator

I'm writing code that produces a left or right facing arrow depending on the users input. It took me ages to figure out the logic for a right facing arrow, and now I can't seem to do the same for a left facing arrow. 
My code:

```
#Sets accumulator value
x = 0
#Prompts user to input desired number of columns
c = int(input('What'))
d = str.lower(input ("What direction left (l) or right (r)?:"))
if d == 'r':
    while c <= 0:
        print ("Invalid input.")
        c = int(input("How many columns? "))
    #While x is less than the amount of columns minus one(This is how we get our forward arrow.
    while(x < c-1):
        print(x*' ' + '*')
        #Adds one to x each time loop itterates
        x +=1 
    #While x is greater than 0
    while(x >= 0):
        #Print blank space x number of times and print '*' after that
        print(x*' ' + '*')
        #Subtracts one from x each time loop itterates
        x -= 1
if d == 'l':
```

Comment: What kind of arrow? You can also just use a unicode for a arrow

Comment: I have to use while loops. I simply want an arrow to print with the user designated amount of columns. So if c == 3 and d == r a 3 column right facing arrow would print. However I cannot get the left facing arrow code down

Comment: Has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is going to be the solution for you, understanding out of your question and the comments.

```
If ( c == 3 && d == "r a") {
    *Your columns + unicode ➡*
}
```

Unicodes can be found here : http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html